# How do I execute/run Ruby code in Sublime Text 2 (Windows)?

Tags: sublimetext2

I have tried using ctrl + B, but all I get in return is  [Finished in 0.3s]. Do I need to download a package to be able  to use hotkeys? If so, does anyone know where I can find the package I need with good instructions? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> runs the file you are currently viewing in ST2's irc (interactive ruby console).

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (thats the tick/tilda button) opens the irc for your currently viewed project.

These are good for linux, osx, and windows, assuming no other packages or key bindings override these default commands.

Also, note that the console is your systems Python in OSX, and a Python interpreter in Windows and linux.

Good, searchable documentation is found [here](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basic_concepts.html#the-python-console-and-the-python-api), one of the three suggested links found from ST2's website about documentation [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/support).